# $G$ a finite group, $H$ a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$. If $K$ a subgroup of $G$ of odd order then $K$ contained in H.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $|G:H|=2$. Suppose $K$ a subgroup of $G$ of odd order. Show $K$ is contained in $H$.

I'm stuck. Need a hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup (this is because the left cosets are the same as the right cosets), then consider the image of $K$ in the quotient by $H$.

Comment: Alright thanks I'll work it out. And theres nothing to show, all subgroups of index 2 are normal.

Comment: @Andrew this is true, but simply stating something true doesn't prove that it's true. If you're allowed to use it for this then skip that step.

Comment: So the image of $K$ in $G/H$ is $\pi(K) = \{kH : k \in K\}$ and $\pi(K)$ is a subgroup of $G/H$ which is isomorphic to $Z_{2}$. So $\pi(K)$ is either the trivial subgroup (in which case $K$ is a subgroup of $H$) or $\pi(K) \cong Z_{2}$ in which case $\pi(K)$ contains an element of order $2$. But the order order of $\pi(k)$ for any $k\in K$ divides the order of $k$, which is not divisible by $2$ because $K$ has odd order, so we can't have the latter case. I think this works.

Answer (score 1):

Since $H$ is normal, going modulo $H$ we can assume that $|G|=2$. Now in group of order $2$, what could be the subgroup of odd order?

Comment: Thanks. I had figured this out (see my reply to the original comment)

Comment: yes, it is essentially same argument.