# Quick question for a statement I'm trying to prove with an odd order...

Tags: proof-explanation

Statement: Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup with $[G:H]=8$. Assume $G/H$ is a quotient group. If $g\in G$ has odd order, then $g\in H$.

I don't quite understand this concept of $[G:H] = 8$ and how it connects to proving an element in $G$ has an odd order.  Just looking for a quick clarification on this aspect of the proof.  Thank you!

Comment: It is perhaps a typo, the index should be $2$, so that $H$ is normal. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312545/g-a-finite-group-h-a-subgroup-of-index-2-in-g-if-k-a-subgroup-of-g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ be the order of $g$.  Note that $(gH)^m = g^m H = eH = H$, so the order of $gH$ must divide the odd number $m$.  But since the order of $G/H$ is 8 we also know that the order of $gH$ must divide $8$.  Hence the order of $gH$ must be $1$, and so $gH=H$.  Hence $g \in H$.

So, what mattered was that $[G:H]=8$ gives the size of the quotient group $G/H$, and this had no odd divisors.

(You are tacitly assuming that $H$ is normal if $G/H$ is to be a group.)

Comment: So essentially we show that the order of $gH$ being 1 shows that since $G$ must have an odd order, the only odd number divisible by 8 is 1.

Comment: The order of $gH \in G/H$ being $1$ means that it must be the identity element, which is $H$.  But $gH = H$ if and only if $g \in H$.